# Django: Order by Time in DateTime Field

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a datetime field.

```
date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Im trying to do a query set for all the entries on that date and then order it by time. I get all the entries like this...

```
todays_entries = model.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

I understand if I wanted to order it by date i would add a order_by('date') method but the time is still all off in terms of the order...how can I go about ordering the time?

Comment: Are you saying `order_by('date')` result in an ordering by dates, but the times within each day are not ordered? Like it would go 1/1/2015 5:00, 1/1/2015 3:00, 1/1/2015 7:00, 1/2/2015 6:00?

Comment: Yes exactly.  I thought maybe there is some different approach required or something.

Comment: how do you populate the date field? If it's just a time stamp, define it as date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True). Then the order_by('-date') will work (just an example for latest first ordering)

Comment: @Pynchia what does auto_now_add have to do with order_by? order_by ought to work regardless of the auto_now_add property

Comment: I parse an xml file. The field is like : 2015-07-04 06:35, and its stored into the model field i mentioned above

Comment: @R.J.Jackson Would you mind giving us the result of `[_.date for _ in model.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date)).order_by('date').all()[0:5]]`? And if that's not long enough to show the problem adjust the `0:5` part until it is large enough.

Comment: When I run the code you mentioned it actually orders it properly...but when I do the above code i posted it doesn't...I'm trying to rap my head around this lol.

Comment: [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) is simply an instance of datetime.datetime. If you are parsing a value try creating it with datetime.strptime(). Or datetime.datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]]) See examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)